# Determine if a Python string contains any kind of quote character

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a regex that will determine if a string contains any kind of single or double quotation mark character, including the specialty ones that you find in Word etc. Is there a list somewhere of what all the special characters are that a human would read as an opening or closing single or double quote, and how those would be represented in a Python string and in a Python regex?

e.g.,
“fancy quoted” ‘single quoted’ "plan text quotes" or 'single quotes' or `backquotes` -- are there others and how can I include these characters in a python regex?

Comment: `from unidecode import unidecode` and then ``if any(c in ['"', "'", "`"] for c in unidecode(text))``.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That seems like something that could be turned into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any regex grouping for quotes, so you will have to come up with a list of characters that you want to match.

Here is the regex expression and the code for what you want.

```
r'''[^“”‘’"'`]'''
```

This code creates a character class that matches with any character that is not those apostrophes/quotation marks. regex substitutes those matched characters with nothing. If there are any quotation marks/apostrophes they will be leftover in the resultant string.

```
string = '''“fancy quoted” ‘single quoted’ "plan text quotes" or 'single quotes' or `backquotes` -- are'''

if re.sub('''[^“”‘’"'`]''', '', string):
    print('Match.')
```